# How to get MatstepLabel in component of Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using this example- 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/amjgpjxbpak?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts

Can any one tell us how to get matStepLabel name in component.

Comment: do you want the value you typed in each label in component?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by getting label name?

Comment: @NinjaJami Not typed value but yes..label name .  I want to pass those values to Api furthur

Comment: @sog did you tried my answer?

Comment: @Code-EZ You answer finds the _form value_ not _matStepLabel_ .

Comment: can you explain a little more? You want to get matStepLabel like 'Fill out your name' while submitting?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there is no clean solution, even if you dig into the Angular Material source. Accessing the `MatStepLabel` is simple, but then actually getting the label from it seems almost impossible.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfgxso?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts)
is a stackblitz that shows how to access the step label, but be aware
it is quite ugly.

It accesses the `MatStepper` via `@ViewChild`, retrieves the three `MatStepHeader` and then via `nativeElement` finds the actual `innerText` / `textContent` of the node.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Stepper overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css'],
})
export class StepperOverviewExample implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  isLinear = false;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild(MatStepper) matStepper: MatStepper;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.matStepper._stepHeader.toArray()[0]._element.nativeElement.childNodes[2].innerText);
    console.log(this.matStepper._stepHeader.toArray()[1]._element.nativeElement.childNodes[2].innerText);
    console.log(this.matStepper._stepHeader.toArray()[2]._element.nativeElement.childNodes[2].innerText);

    console.log(this.matStepper._stepHeader.toArray()[0]._element.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-step-label').textContent);
    console.log(this.matStepper._stepHeader.toArray()[1]._element.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-step-label').textContent);
    console.log(this.matStepper._stepHeader.toArray()[2]._element.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-step-label').textContent);
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting ` Property '_elementRef' is protected and only accessible within class 'CdkStepHeader' and its subclasses.`